# MySQL/MariaDB: Create a dynamic report with a pivot table view

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot, report

I have this **MySQL (MariaDB)** table:

```
+----+--------+-------+---------+
| id | date   |planned| actual  |
+----+--------+-------+---------+
|  1 |03-04-23| 40    |      15 |
|  2 |03-04-23| 15    |      17 |
|  3 |03-04-23| 60    |      19 |
|  4 |03-04-23| 20    |      20 |
|  1 |04-04-23| 10    |      22 |
|  2 |04-04-23| 15    |      32 |
|  3 |04-04-23| 65    |      50 |
|  4 |04-04-23| 22    |      55 |
|  1 |05-04-23| 18    |      40 |
|  2 |05-04-23| 36    |      65 |
|  3 |05-04-23| 44    |      70 |
|  4 |05-04-23| 47    |      57 |
+----+--------+-------+---------+
```

I need a report like this:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| user_id |    03-04-23  |    04-04-23  |   05-04-23    | 
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|         |Planned|Actual|Planned|Actual|Planned|Actual |
+---------+--------------+------------------------------+
|      1  |  40   |  15  |   10  |  22  |   18  | 40    |
|      2  |  15   |  17  |   15  |  32  |   36  | 65    |
|      3  |  60   |  19  |   65  |  50  |   44  | 70    |
|      4  |  20   |  20  |   22  |  55  |   47  | 57    |
+---------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I have to provide a date range. For example: 01-04-2023 to 30-04-2023.

The report should generate columns for each date dynamically and the data should be shown only for the dates in which data is available.

I have used the following query and have generated the columns dynamically.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(selected_date) = ''',
           DATE(selected_date),
           ''' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `',
           DATE(selected_date),
           '`')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) selected_date
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2023-04-01' AND '2023-04-30';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ADDDATE(''1970-01-01'', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) selected_date
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN ''2023-04-01'' AND ''2023-04-30''');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I don't get how to link up this result set with the existing table. Also I'm not able to run this query straight in Metabase to generate a report. So I'm thinking of creating a procedure and then to call the procedure in Metabase.

What's the best way to move forward?